# PHP, how to use a character as a variable name?

Tags: php, variables

Good day,

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can use a character stored inside a variable to call another variable by name. For instance:

```
$string = "ABCD";
$A = 10;
echo //Here I want to get $string[0]'s value, which will be A, then echo the value of the variable named after $string[0]'s value, $A. So in other words the output of the echo should be 10.
```

Let me know if I'm not clear enough on the question.

Comment: `echo ${$string[0]};`?

Comment: The logic is called _variables of variable_, and @Darren is correct here.

Comment: be careful with variable variables, since they *almost never* result in clean, maintainable code. except for purely academic code, you should try to avoid them whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to [PHP Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable.

Try one of these:

```
$string = "ABCD";

echo ${$string[0]};  // 10
echo $$string[0];    // 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. I tried using variable variables, but it didn't print out anything. I realized that it's because I defaulted all the variable to false.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO,

As per your asking about **Let me know if I'm not clear enough on the question.**, I love this one cause you are new to this site. Now lets go to the field.

You have a variable: `$string = "ABCD";`, and also another is `$A = 10;`, or `$B = 10;` and so on.

What you really want to know is how to get the same value using the `$string` values??

**Solution:**
The logic behind this is called [variables.variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), Let you are using the index of the string.

```
$string = "ABCD"; // your variable
$A = 10;          // your another variable
$B = 10;          // may your another variable
```

Now, Let `$string[0]`, In this variable we have the a value and the value is `A`, So if we put a `$` sign before this value then what will happen?? This will create a new variable and if you echo it you will get the value of this new created variable if the variable has a value.

**Just do it:** `echo ${$string[0]};` // 10

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `$arr1 = str_split($str);` to get an array of chars, and then based on that array do the echo like this `echo "$$arr1[0]"`